# Downloading a rar file with requests.get and writing the content into a file issue on python

Tags: python, python-requests

Actually the perfect solution would be a reading the .rar file into system memory (variable) and extract directly into variables and use them to requests post on an API.

But since I did not found a solution on reading a .rar file into system memory I am working with a tmp directory. The extracting of the .rar files is working flawless as far as I can tell with my test.rar file. But the downloading of the .rar file and writing it to the current working directory is not working correctly. I get empty .rar files even doh the size is almost correct about 1kb difference.

here is my code:

```
import requests
import os


link = 'https://filebin.net/r3m0ll3uo8xvpb34/test.rar?t=p4cx324b'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0'}
data = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
with open('tmp.rar', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data.content)
# unrar('tmp.rar')
os.remove('tmp.rar')
```

Comment: change `w` to `wb` as you writing binary.

Comment: The website changes the file-url after some time. The link in your example is old now so the website redirects it to the webpage. So after some time you download this webpage instead of the file.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη

the issue was really the wb instead of the w.